# What is the name of $C(A)/A$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Given a topological space $A$, $C(A)$ is the cone of $A$. The space $C(A)/A$ is clearly homotopic to the suspension. My question is if it has a widely known name?

Comment: Isn't this **homeomorphic** to the suspension? I assume you mean $C(A)/(A\times\{0\})$.

Comment: double cone or suspension (don't confuse it with the reduced suspension $A \wedge \mathbb{S}^1$).

Comment: @StefanH I asked a stupid question. What in my mind is asking the name for the simplicial set $\Delta^0 \star A\cup_{A} \Delta^0$ the pushout for the canonical maps $A\subset \Delta^0 \star A$ and $A\to \Delta^0$ for a simplicial set $A$, where star is the simplicial join (a cone).

Answer (score 1):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

Taken from the comments:

$C(A)/A$ is homeomorphic to the suspension of $A$. Therefore it does not need a separate name.